# Conditional v-once directive

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on an app that uses Vue. It is a kind of document editor that allows editing of content.

There's a filmstrip in a sidebar displaying the entirety of the document, and a viewport in the center displaying the current page/spread.

On large documents with 100+ pages, I'd like to throttle the number of updates allowed through to the filmstrip component as it gets a little laggy on resize and when the JS controlled layouts in pages all have to resize simultaneously when global fields are changed etc.

There's a data structure representing the document's content, which is rendered by Vue components in the viewport and the filmstrip.

I could maintain two data structures and only update the data structure used in the filmstrip 1000ms after the last user interaction.

However, it feels like there could be a better way.

Vue has a directive called `v-once`, which looks promising, however, I can't find out if that can be set conditionally.

If I could, then I could set a timeout on change, and clear it if a change occurs before the timeout ends, and then momentarily unset `v-once`, then on next tick, add it back on again so that rendering pauses.

If there's a way of doing this, I'd love to know.

Comment: Who the hell voted that this question is too broad? It is actually very specific, if you're going to make such a determination, why not let me know your reasoning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here [Proposal: Allowing v-once to accept a boolean flag](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6407#issuecomment-323964496) is very clear, you can't set `v-once` dynamically. Also there is an example of one way to combine `v-if` and `v-once` to achieve the result you want.

Excerpt from the link

> v-once is used for static content. v-once tell the compiler don't add any responsive functionalities to save cpu time. Otherwise, if the content is responsive, no methods could be used to save this kind of cpu time.

Hope it helped

Comment: Hi there, thanks for finding that. Implementing the suggested workaround in my case is not so simple. Since there are many thousands of component instances with JS controlled layouts that would have to be rendered whenever `v-if` received a truthy value, it would cause significant lag. I'd have to implemented at the level of pages in the filmstrip I mentioned. Guess that's what I'll have to do then!